# Selenium : getting next button click content

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, quora

On Quora website, i am trying to get upvoters names of each answer, by clicking on 'view upvoters', but i am not getting the right results.
For example, On [this](https://www.quora.com/What-alt-coins-are-easily-mineable) Quora question link you have two answers, first one with 5 upvoters and second one with 2.  The result i am getting from the below code is 5,5 .

```
all_upvotes= browser.find_elements_by_class_name('ExpandedVoterListItem')
for p in all_upvotes:
    p.click()
    time.sleep(10)

    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.modal_content.modal_body'))) 

    upvoter_name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.feed_item_answer_user'))) 

    time.sleep(10)
    print ('number of upvoters found for this answer %d' % len(upvoter_name)) 
    # print upvoters names
    for line in upvoter_name:
           print(line.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't select "View Upvoters" link every time, at least in the script you provided. Instead, use the following order of operations:

```
all_upvotes= browser.find_elements_by_link_text('View Upvoters') # Finds all "View Upvoters" buttons (they are links actually)
for p in all_upvotes:

    p.click() # Opens list of upvoters

    # No need to sleep or wait for anything else, just wait for items you want, namely the name of upvoter (which is again a link):
    upvoter_name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.user')))

    print ('number of upvoters found for this answer %d' % len(upvoter_name)) 

    # print upvoters names
    for line in upvoter_name:
        print(line.text)

    # Now we need to close list of upvoters, to open the next one on next iteration of the loop:
    close_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.modal_close'))) 
    close_button.click()
```